# Highcharts Single Line series JSON date data format

Tags: json, highcharts

I am trying to implement the Single Line series chart here: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

I see the JSON format for the report is as follows:

```
/* May 2006 */
[1147651200000,67.79],
[1147737600000,64.98],
[1147824000000,65.26],
[1147910400000,63.18],
[1147996800000,64.51],
[1148256000000,63.38],
[1148342400000,63.15],
[1148428800000,63.34],
[1148515200000,64.33],
[1148601600000,63.55],
[1148947200000,61.22],
[1149033600000,59.77],
```

How do I change my data format of [date, count] into the format above?

eg my format **["2013-01-01", 55],**

Thanks for any light you can shed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript function Date.UTC which will do the conversion for you. e.g.

```
[Date.UTC(2013,0,1),55],
```

Note, the Javascript months start at 0 (for Jan), not 1.

N.B. Make sure your axis type is 'datetime'.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP do this:

```
 $timestamp =  1000 * strtotime($your_date);
```